# How to get this value as a CGFloat?

Tags: iphone, casting

I am asking for an Value like this:

```
[self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"]
```

bit I need to pass it to a method which takes a CGFloat as parameter. What's the casting trick here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Swift:

```
let f = view.layer.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z")!.floatValue
```

In Objective-C:

```
NSNumber* n = [self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
CGFloat f = [n floatValue];
```

Comment: Wrong, `floatValue` is `float`, while `CGFloat` is `double` on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: You’re re right! Here’s an answer that does it properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/34301580/22147

Comment: Or just `ifdef` on `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a more concise, one line way to do that, you can do:

```
CGFloat f = [[self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```