# Conversion between CGFloat and NSNumber without unnecessary promotion to Double

Tags: swift, nsnumber, cgfloat

As we all know, `CGFloat` (which is ubiquitous in CoreGraphics, UIKit etc)
can be a 32-bit or 64-bit floating point number, depending on the
processor architecture.

In C, `CGFloat` it is a typealias
to `float` or `double`, in Swift is it defined as a `struct CGFloat` with
a `native` property (which is `Float` or `Double`).

It has been observed repeatedly that a `NSNumber` can be created from
and converted to `Float` and `Double`, but that there exist not
similar conversions from and to `CGFloat`. The general advice
(e.g. in [Convert CGFloat to NSNumber in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278923/convert-cgfloat-to-nsnumber-in-swift)) is to
convert via `Double`

```
CGFloat <--> Double <--> NSNumber
```

Example:

```
let c1 = CGFloat(12.3)
let num = NSNumber(double: Double(c1))
let c2 = CGFloat(num.doubleValue)
```

and that is simple and correct, no precision is lost.
Also most platforms are 64-bit nowadays, and then the `CGFloat/Double`
conversion is trivial and probably optimized by the compiler.

However, it aroused my curiosity if a conversion can be done
*without* promoting `CGFloat` to `Double` on 32-bit platforms.

One could use a *build configuration statement* (as e.g. in [Should conditional compilation be used to cope with difference in CGFloat on different architectures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184810/should-conditional-compilation-be-used-to-cope-with-difference-in-cgfloat-on-dif/24189648#24189648)):

```
extension NSNumber {
    convenience init(cgFloatValue value : CGFloat) {
        #if arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
            self.init(double: value.native)
        #else
            self.init(float: value.native)
        #endif
    }
}
```

But what if Swift is ported to other architectures which are not
Intel or ARM? This does not look very future proof.

One could also use the `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` constant (as e.g. in
[NSNumber from CGFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067723/nsnumber-from-cgfloat/17067896#17067896)):

```
    if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE != 0 {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
```

The disadvantage here is that the compiler will always emit a
*"Will never be executed"* warning on one of the cases.

So to make the long story short:

- How can we convert between
  `CGFloat` and `NSNumber` in a safe way, without compiler warnings,
  and without unnecessary promotion to `Double`?

Please note that this is meant as an "academic" problem. As mentioned
above (and in other Q&A's) one can simply convert via `Double`
practically.

I am posting a "self-answer" here in the spirit of
[share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Of course other answers are welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update:** One can cast a `CGFloat` value to `NSNumber` and back:

```
let c1 = CGFloat(12.3)
let num = c1 as NSNumber
let c2 = num as CGFloat
```

This preserves the precision of `CGFloat` and works with Swift 2
and Swift 3.

---

*(Previous answer – far too complicated):* There are two solutions that I found. The first uses the toll-free bridging
between `NSNumber` and `CFNumber` (as in [What is most common and correct practice to get a CGFloat from an NSNumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231310/what-is-most-common-and-correct-practice-to-get-a-cgfloat-from-an-nsnumber/21231543#21231543)
for Objective-C). It uses the fact that `CFNumber` *has* a dedicated
conversion mode for `CGFloat` values:

```
extension NSNumber {

    // CGFloat -> NSNumber
    class func numberWithCGFloat(var value: CGFloat) -> NSNumber {
        return CFNumberCreate(nil , .CGFloatType, &value)
    }

    // NSNumber -> CGFloat
    var cgFloatValue : CGFloat {
        var value : CGFloat = 0
        CFNumberGetValue(self, .CGFloatType, &value)
        return value
    }
}
```

That is simple and nice. The only drawback: I could not figure out
how to make the constructor an `init` method instead of a `class method`.

The second possible solution is a bit longer:

```
extension NSNumber {

    // CGFloat -> NSNumber
    private convenience init(doubleOrFloat d : Double) {
        self.init(double : d)
    }
    private convenience init(doubleOrFloat f : Float) {
        self.init(float : f)
    }
    convenience init(cgFloat : CGFloat) {
        self.init(doubleOrFloat: cgFloat.native)
    }

    // NSNumber -> CGFloat
    private func doubleOrFloatValue() -> Double {
        return self.doubleValue
    }
    private func doubleOrFloatValue() -> Float {
        return self.floatValue
    }
    var cgFloatValue : CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(floatLiteral: doubleOrFloatValue())
    }
}
```

There are two private "helper" init methods with the same external
parameter name `doubleOrFloat` but different parameter types. From the actual
type of `cgFloat.native` the compiler determines which one to call
in

```
    convenience init(cgFloat : CGFloat) {
        self.init(doubleOrFloat: cgFloat.native)
    }
```

Same idea in the accessor method. From the type of `self.native`
the compiler determines which of the two `doubleOrFloatValue()`
methods to call in

```
    var cgFloatValue : CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(floatLiteral: doubleOrFloatValue())
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that as of April 2017, with Swift 3.1 released, the cast between NSNumber and CGFloat may fail at runtime and will become a checked cast in Swift 4, so the more convoluted solution might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
let num = NSNumber(double: 1.0)
let c: CGFloat? = CGFloat(exactly: num)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/2882773-init) for the initializer.